# Session class doesn’t work online

Tags: codeigniter

I have a trouble with Session class when I put my website online.
When I login to the website, the session is create and everything works but
when I logout, the session doesn’t destroy. I don’t know why because in local
that works fine.

My code to destroy the session :

```
<?php
    function logout()
    {
        $this->session->unset_userdata('login');
        $this->session->unset_userdata('logged');
        $this->session->sess_destroy();
        redirect(site_url());
    }
?>
```

I though to use native session but I need session class because I have a minichat
on my website and I need to get people online thanks to the session.

Someone have an idea of my trouble ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: How do you know that the session doesn't destroy?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help. 
Because when I look at the the table « ci_session », the session is still display

Answer (score 0):

Check out CodeIgniter's source code for `sess_destroy()`:
https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/libraries/Session.php#L549

This is the piece you're interested in:

```
// Kill the session DB row
if ($this->sess_use_database === TRUE && isset($this->userdata['session_id']))
{
    $this->CI->db->where('session_id', $this->userdata['session_id']);
    $this->CI->db->delete($this->sess_table_name);
}
```

Make sure that both of these conditions are true.

Comment: Hi, Thank you very much for your help. Unfortunately it doesn't work. It's really really weird… I try to delete the session by myself like this:
`$this->db->where('session_id',$this->session->userdata('session_id'));
$this->db->delete('ci_sessions');`

It works fine in local but it doesn't work online and I really don't know why, it's just delete a row…

Comment: And I checked, it's the good session_id. Do you think that maybe I don't have the permission to delete something in the table ci_sessions ?

Comment: CodeIgniter error handling: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/errors.html

Comment: I have tried to delete a row in the PhpMyAdmin and it works !! It doesn't work when I try with CI, someone has an idea ?